# asp.net MVC Validation Returning new View with validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

When I click my 'continue' button my form generates a new view of the fields being validated and shows whats missing.  How do I get the validations to show on the same partialview.

My controller:

```
namespace LoanApp.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // This is how we prepopulate the list of loan types. Doing it here b/c one day this will be from a list from a service.
        var vm = new Step1ViewModel();

        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes = new List<string>();
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("Auto Refinance");
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("Auto Purchase");
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("Auto PreApproval");
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("Signature Loan");
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("Credit Card");
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("Home Equity");
        vm.AllAvailableLoanTypes.Add("10 Year 1st Mortgage");
        return View(vm);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectLoanType(Step1ViewModel model)
    {
        // For this example I slapped the type in Session, you could post it through in each subsequent viewmodel and just hide it on the form in a Html.Hidden()
        Session["LoanType"] = model.LoanType;
        return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");



    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PrimaryApplicant(PrimaryApplicantViewModel model)
    {

        // Make sure session didnt get eaten.
        var loanType = "";
        if (Session["LoanType"] != null)
        {
            loanType = Session["LoanType"].ToString();

        }

        // Here we decide which view to show next. in the frotn end you may need to handle what to change labels to in the wizard maybe via JQ/JS
        switch (loanType)
        {
            case "Auto Refinance":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("AutoRefinance");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            case "Auto Purchase":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("AutoPurchase");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            case "Auto PreApproval":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("AutoPreApproval");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            case "Signature Loan":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("SignatureLoan");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            case "Credit Card":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("CreditCard");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            case "Home Equity":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("HomeEquity");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            case "10 Year 1st Mortgage":
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return PartialView("TenYearFirstMortgage");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Information Incomplete");
                    return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
                }
            default:
                return PartialView("PrimaryApplicantPartial");
        }


    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AutoRefinance(AutoRefinanceViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("AutoRefinanceFinal");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AutoPurchase(AutoPurchaseViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("NextView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AutoPreApproval(AutoPreApprovalViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("NextView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignatureLoan(SignatureLoanViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("NextView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreditCard(CreditCardViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("NextView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HomeEquity(HomeEquityViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("NextView");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TenYearFirstMortgage(TenYearFirstMortgageViewModel model)
    {
        //do stuff here

        // This will fail for now with a lovely 500
        return PartialView("NextView");
    }
}
```

}

You will see the validation code above.  And this is my partialview:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model LoanApp.Models.PrimaryApplicantViewModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

<script>

$("input[name='JointOwner']").change(function () {
    $("#JointApplicantInfo").toggle();
});
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#dob").mask("99/99/9999");
    $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
    $("#zip").mask("99999");
});


</script>



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PrimaryApplicant", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "step3", OnSuccess = "showStep3"     }))
{
<h4>Primary Applicant Information</h4>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<hr/>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First Name" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Middle Name" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Last Name" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SSN, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SSN, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Social Security Number", id = "ssn" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SSN)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Date of Birth", id = "dob" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DOB)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", placeholder = "Email Address" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Phone Number", id = "phone" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address1, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address1, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Address 1" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address2, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Address 2" })
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address1)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "City" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.State, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "State" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.State)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Zip Code", id = "zip" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Zip)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HousingPayment, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HousingPayment, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Housing Payment" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HousingPayment)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HousingType, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Housing Type" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HousingType)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmploymentType, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentType, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Employment Type" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmploymentType)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmployerName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployerName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Employer Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmployerName)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmploymentTitle, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentTitle, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Title" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmploymentTitle)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmploymentStartDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmploymentStartDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", placeholder = "Employment Start Date" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmploymentStartDate)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Monthly Income" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MonthlyIncome)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalIncome, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalIncome, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalIncome)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeSource, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeSource, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Source" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeSource)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Amount" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AdditionalIncomeAmt)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "form-control", value = "0" }, new { @checked = "" })&nbsp;No</label>
                <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.JointOwner, new { @class = "form-control", value = "1" })&nbsp;Yes</label>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    //Joint Applicant
    <div id="JointApplicantInfo">

        <h4>Joint Applicant Information</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointFirstName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointFirstName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "First Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointFirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointMiddleName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Middle Name" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointLastName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Last Name" })
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointSsn, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointSsn, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Social Security Number", id = "ssm" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointSsn)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointDob, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointDob, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Date of Birth", id = "dob" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointDob)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointEmail, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointEmail, new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", placeholder = "Email Address" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointEmail)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointPhoneNumber, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Phone Number", id = "phone" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointPhoneNumber)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointAddress1, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointAddress1, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Address 1" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointAddress1)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointAddress2, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Address 2" })
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointCity, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "City" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointCity)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointState, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "State" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointState)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointZip, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Zip Code" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointZip)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointHousingPayment, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointHousingPayment, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Housing Payment" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointHousingPayment)
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointHousingType, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Housing Type" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointHousingType)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointEmploymentType, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointEmploymentType, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Employment Type" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointEmploymentType)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointEmployerName, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointEmployerName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Employer Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointEmployerName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointEmploymentTitle, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointEmploymentTitle, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Title" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointEmploymentTitle)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointEmploymentStartDate, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointEmploymentStartDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", placeholder = "Employment Start Date" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointEmploymentStartDate)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointMonthlyIncome, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointMonthlyIncome, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Monthly Income" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointMonthlyIncome)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncome, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncome, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncome)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncomeSource, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncomeSource, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Source" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncomeSource)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncomeAmt, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Additional Income Amount" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JointAdditionalIncomeAmt)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you trying to do is you want to return the partial view with the validation if it fail ( Model state) and you need to redirect or pass another one if modelstate is valid.

If you want to do above scenario you can do combination of jquery and json

Submit the form using jquery (Serialized form) to the post method and return the json result if you want to redirect to somewhere else

please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's exactly what i want to do.  I don't have a clue as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are in right track just try these few steps.

Put a condition on your controller to your model state is valid or not

On your controller you need to return the json object which has the route url with the parameters.

On controller

return Json( new { redirectToAction = Url.Action( "ActionResult", "Controller", new {Parameters = parameters } ) } );

And you jquery function should be 
For default bind add pass your url as a string to the jquery function.

function SubmitForm(routUrl) {

```
 var serializedForm = $("# YourFormName ").serialize();;

 $.ajax({

     url: routUrl, 
     cache: false,
     type: "POST",
     data: serializedForm,
     success: function (data) {


         if (data.redirectToAction) {

             window.location.href = data.redirectToAction;
         }
         else {

             $("#YourFormName").html(data);
         }


     }

 });
```

}

Let me know if you need more details, hope this will help you.

Comment: What would I put for the parameters?